# Page Tab not consistently showing up

Tags: heroku, tabs, facebook-page

I recently set up an app on Facebook to utilize the page tab feature for a business page I admin. I used the Heroku hosting and believe I set it up correctly because I am able to see it when I click on the tab icon from my page.  However it will often go to a blank screen with this error

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Then later it will show up again???

I have been through all the tutorials on the FB developer site about apps, tabs, etc several times and can't figure it out.  Although none of them give detailed instructions based on how the app set up looks now and with the whole Heroku thing.

I only have "page tab" checked on how my app integrates with FB.  Do I need a canvas page? In page tab URL/secure URL I have entered the website I want to show up in the tab.  App domain is the domain of my company's website. When adding the app to my page using the install link given `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL` I used the Heroku url for `Your_URL`.

Do I need to make any edits in `Heroku`?

Please advise and thanks for the help!

Comment: That error appears to be from your browser or from heroku's side - is there anything in the logs on heroku's side?